# change “None” to blank in HTML table

Tags: html

I have a web app， frontend using HTML5, backend using Django and MySQL.
Some column is NULL in MySQL,  it shows "None" in the HTML table.

How could I change all None to blank in HTML table？

```
               <table>
  <tr>
    <th>S/N</th>
    <th>Course Material Title</th>
      <th>Author/Editor</th>
      <th>Publication Year</th>
                      <th>Edition</th>
                <th>Special Edition</th>
    <th>iSBN or  e-iSBN / VBID</th>
      <th>Cost</th>
      <th>Material Format</th>
      <th>Distribution Mode</th>



  </tr>
{% for query_results_book in query_results_books_list %}
  <tr>
      <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
      {% for obj in query_results_book %}
      {% if obj.title == "StudyGuide" or  obj.title == "Mylab" %}
      <td>{{ obj.title }}</td>
      {% else %}
    <td>{{obj.title}}</td>
      {% endif %}
            <td>{{obj.author}}</td>
                                            <td>{{obj.pub_date}}</td>
                        <td>{{obj.edition}}</td>
                        <td>{{obj.special_edition}}</td>

      {% if obj.Format_issued == "eText" %}
      <td>{{ obj.vbid }}</td>
      {% else %}
       <td>{{ obj.isbn }}</td>
      {% endif %}
                    {% if obj.e_price %}
      <td>{{obj.e_price_cur}}{{obj.e_price}}</td>
          {% else %}
          <td></td>
          {% endif %}
  <td>{{obj.Format_issued}}</td>

            <td>{{obj.Distribution_platform}}</td>


      {%endfor%}
  </tr>
{%endfor%}
</table>
```

Some data in mysql is NULL， it shows "None" in this HTML table. Boss want to show it blank instead.

Comment: You need to show us the **rendered** HTML too.

Comment: You need to fix your Django template's indentation: your `<th>` elements should all be vertically aligned but right now it's a hard-to-read mess which is harder to maintain.

Comment: Your `<table>` is using an implicit `<tbody>` which means your header row won't be machine-readable. You should use an explicit `<thead>` and `<tbody>` elements (don't forget to use `<th>` instead of `<td>` inside your `<thead>`).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to do this in the place where you are passing the data e.g:

```
<td>{obj.name || ""}</td>
```

So, `obj.name || ""` this will replace all nullish value with an empty string/black

Comment: got an error using ur method： filter name expected

Comment: No i mean, replace obj with the object you are accessing and then replace the name with the property/or method you trying to access because its dynamic:

obj.sampleMethod() || ""
obj.anyProperty || ""

Do you get, if not, post a screengrap of the error?